# Add users and groups to other groups and get all the hierarchy to top using sql

Tags: sql

I want to make a group policies in a way that I can assign users to groups and groups to other groups so I have created a database table

```
table groups { Type, EntityID, GroupID }
```

The type could be 1 for users and 2 for groups

For example if I have an entity with type 1 and `entityID = 1` and `groupid = 2`
this means that the user of id 1 belong to a group of id 2 and so on, same for the groups of type 2

When a group has `groupID = NULL` then this is a root Group which means that this group does not have a parent group.

I want to write a select query that return all the hierarchy of a groups that a user belong to

`Groups` table

```
ID  Type Entity GroupID
-----------------------    
    1   2   1   NULL
    2   2   2   1
    3   2   3   NULL
    4   2   4   3
    5   2   5   4
    6   2   6   5
    7   2   7   6
    8   1   1   6
```

For example the last row contains a user that is belong to group 6 and group 6 belong to g5 and g5 belong to g4 and g4 belong to g3 and g3 is a root group

So if I run the query it should return result like this

```
Type EntityID GroupID
2   3   NULL
2   4   3
2   5   4
2   6   5
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cte

just copy the code below

```
    WITH UserBelongTo (Type,EntityID,GroupID)
AS
(
    select a.Type, a.EntityID, a.GroupID from Groups a 
    where a.EntityID in  (select Groups.GroupID from Groups where EntityID=1 and Type=1)
    and a.Type=2

    union all
    select a.Type, a.EntityID, a.GroupID from Groups a 
    inner join UserBelongTo c on c.GroupID=a.EntityID
    where  a.Type=2
)   

select distinct  * from UserBelongTo
```